# Problematic data array crashes app in Java when program runs its lines of code

Tags: java, android

For Reference, this is my Code:

```
package com.example.scoutingapp2019v9;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

import static android.provider.AlarmClock.EXTRA_MESSAGE;

public class EndgameEntryActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    RadioButton end_level1;
    RadioButton end_level2;
    RadioButton end_level3;
    String[] data;
    String fileName;
    String path;
    String[] labels;
    Button savedata;
    EditText comments;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_endgame_entry);


        data = new String[14];
//        Intent intent = getIntent();
//        String[] autoEntryData = intent.getStringArrayExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE);
//        for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
//            data[i] = autoEntryData[i];
//        }
        labels = new String[]{"Team Number", "Event", "Match Number", "Alliance", "Start Position", "Exited HabZone", "Number of HatchPanels Placed in Sandstorm", "Number of Cargo Placed in Sandstorm", "Teleop Number of HatchPanels Placed in Rockets", "Teleop Number of Cargo Placed in Rockets", "Teleop Number of HatchPanels Placed in CargoShip", "Teleop Number of Cargo Placed in CargoShip", "End Position", "Comments"};
        savedata = (Button) findViewById(R.id.savedata);
        final RadioButton rb9 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.end_level1);
        final RadioButton rb10 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.end_level2);
        final RadioButton rb11 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.end_level3);
        final RadioButton rb12 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.end_level_0);
        comments = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.comments);
        savedata.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (rb9.isSelected()) {
                    data[12] = ("Level 1");
                } else if (rb10.isSelected()) {
                    data[12] = ("Level 2");
                } else if (rb11.isSelected()) {
                    data[12] = ("Level 3");
                } else if (rb12.isSelected()) {
                    data[12] = ("DNF");
                }
                data[13] = comments.getText().toString();
                saveData(data, labels);
            }
        });
    }
    private void saveData(String[] saveData, String[] saveLabels){
        path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/Documents/TeamData2019/";//temporarily without subfolder
        fileName = data[0] + "_" + data[1] + "_" + data[2] + ".json";
        try{
            new File(path).mkdir();
            path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/Documents/TeamData2019/" + data[1] + '/';
            new File(path).mkdir();
            File file = new File(path + fileName);
            if (!file.exists()) {
                file.createNewFile();
            }
            else{
                return;
            }
            JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
            for(int i = 0; i < saveData.length; i++){
                obj.put(saveLabels[i],saveData[i]);
            }

            FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(file, true);
            fileWriter.write(obj.toString());
            fileWriter.flush();

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Data saved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

When uncommenting this line of code:

```
//            data[i] = autoEntryData[i];
```

The entire program crashes and fails, and send the application back to the last activity. I think there is an exception occurring that crashes the program, but I do not know how to fix it, and this may be a result of my lack of experience using Java.
Does anyone have any ideas about what is happening, and how to fix it?

Comment: I’d have to guess `IndexOutOfBounds`, likely due to the hardcoded `i < 12` and then using `i` as an index in one or both of your `array`s.

Answer (score 0):

Avoid looping for a fixed number of times.

Instead, get the array length to know where to stop and prevent errors. Something like this:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String[] autoEntryData = intent.getStringArrayExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE);
for (int i = 0; i < autoEntryData.length; i++) {
    data[i] = autoEntryData[i];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's simply because of the following code:

```
String[] data = new String[14];
```

is only allocating a block of memory for your array with the default value of string which is a null. So, whenever you're trying to manipulate an element, you're facing a null value. You either need to handle the null or initializing each elements with empty string `""`.

When you're calling the following code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
    data[i] = autoEntryData[i];
}
```

you're assigning value for 12 elements. So, you won't facing the null value until the 12th elements. Here I assuming that your 12 values is not null.

---

**Suggestion**:

- Always (or often) initialize your non-primitive array with a default value. Though this is not a strict requirement if you want to minimize memory usage.
- Use the size of you array to initialize or modify your array. Something like this:

  ```
  int size = 14;
  String[] data = new String[size];
  // you can also use data.length to get the size of an array.

  for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
      data[i] = "";
  }
  ```